# Eclipse content assist broken only in one file

Tags: eclipse-jdt, content-assist

Content assist always shows "No Default Proposals" in one of my Java classes, but it works as expected elsewhere in the project/workspace.  It worked at one point in that file too, but stopped working for no reason that I can see.

I'm using Eclipse Classic 3.7.1, Java 6 update 30.  My settings are the default in Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced.  I've tried to clean/rebuild project.  I also tried removing and re-adding the class.

Comment: It would be useful to see the class that has the problem.  Also, have a look at your error log for any relevant stack traces.

Comment: Just had the same issue with one file - and I'm running Eclipse 4.3...

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all index database files in your workspace directory

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2/
```

and restart Eclipse. Also close/reopen the file in question.